# How to get combination in python?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list like below, I want to find simple permutation with little bit modification,

For Example

```
l=['a', 'b']
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]
```

I followed,

Try-1

```
list(itertools.product(L, repeat=2))
```

returns,

```
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```

Try -2

```
print list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b']))
```

returns,

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
```

Try-3

i can do like below,

```
temp= [tuple(sorted((i,j))) for i in ['a', 'b'] for j in ['a', 'b']]
print list(set(temp))
```

But it seems inefficient way to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

l=['a', 'b']
for c in combinations_with_replacement(l, 2):
    print(c)
```

**Output**

```
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('b', 'b')
```